# How to represent recursive EBNF grammar in Rust data structures?

Tags: parsing, data-structures, rust, ebnf

Let's say I have the following example EBNF grammar. This is not a perfect grammar, but it should demonstrate the problem correctly.

```
Statement = FunctionDefinition | Assignment | Expr ;
Expr = { Term | "(" , Expr , ")" } ;

Assignment = Word , "=" , Expr ;
FunctionDefinition = Word , { Word } , "=" , Expr ;

Term = Word | Number
```

Where a `Word` is some number of letters and numbers and a `Number` is a valid numeric literal.

I can start to represent this in Rust like so:

```
enum Statement {
    FunctionDefinition {
        name: String,
        params: Vec<String>,
        body: Expr,
    },
    Assignment {
        name: String,
        body: Expr,
    },
    //TODO: Expr
}
```

There is already a problem here though. How do I add `Expr`? `Expr` should probably have its own definition since it is used in several other places as well. Giving `Expr` its own separate definition and then adding it to this enum will redefine it.

If I continue anyway and start trying to define `Expr`, I run into even more problems:

```
type Expr = Vec<...?...>;
// or maybe...
struct Expr {
    terms: Vec<Expr>, // but what about Term??
}
```

I tried to use `type` because `Expr` does not necessarily need to be its own struct or enum since it is just a collection of `Term`s or other `Expr`s. It is difficult to recursively define this though. If I try to use an enum to emulate a union type for Expr and Term, then I have to redefine `Expr` in that enum and define `Term` within the enum which makes Term unavailable in the other structures I will need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Expr` can be a `type` alias, but you need to define an `enum` to represent the alternation. `Term` also needs to be a separate `enum`.

```
enum Statement {
    FunctionDefinition {
        name: String,
        params: Vec<String>,
        body: Expr,
    },
    Assignment {
        name: String,
        body: Expr,
    },
    Expr(Expr),
}

type Expr = Vec<ExprItem>;

enum ExprItem {
    Term(Term),
    Parenthesized(Expr),
}

enum Term {
    Word(String),
    Number(f64),
}
```

Comment: Works great! Thanks! I guess there is no way to get around the `Expr(Expr)` or the `Term(Term)` though. Kind of ugly, but it works.